# Check if an element is displayed and enabled

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am checking if element I am searching for by.Xpath is Displayed and Enabled.
Something like this :

```
 var element = Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[contains(@href,'/Services')]"));

 if (element.Displayed && element.Enabled)
 {
 Result.Pass(52); 
 }
 else  
{
 Result.Fail(52); 
}
```

It is returning Displayed(false) and Enabled(true), 
but the actual element is visible on the website itself.

When I inspect the element on the website it is something like this:

```
<a href="/Services">Services</a>
```

Any suggestions?

*Some more HTML code*:

```
   <ul class="list-unstyled">
                <li class="footer-heading">my website</li>
                <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Search">Item search</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Services">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Services/AreaGuides">Area guides</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Services/Client">Client</a></li>                    
            </ul>
```

Comment: Do you find more than one element with same selector? probably hidden

Comment: @ Raging Bull *You might be correct , there are some other links starting with the same string, any suggestion how to fix this problem ? Because obviously I cannot search if href contains /Services. How can I check for href that match my string?*

Comment: Is that the only element with Services text though?

Comment: @Raging Bull * Well it is though, I presume that you are going to advise me to search by.LinkText , but I would really like to find some more generic solution because text my change*.

Comment: Provide me some more html then. XPath is your best option in that case I assume

Comment: @Raging Bull Please take a look again at my post I added some more HTML code. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alecxe's answer is correct as well. In addition to that if you want some generic way you can try the followings:

with css:

```
ul a[href$='Services']
```

with xpath text based search(I prefer this if the text is static):

```
//a[text()='Services']
```

Comment: ul a[href$='Services'] is this actually searching for exact match of the link?

Comment: @Mystia, see [this blog post](http://ddavison.io/css/2014/02/18/effective-css-selectors.html) to see some difference CSS selectors and how to use them with Selenium.  there are several difference operators to use :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `By.LinkText()` locator:

```
Driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Services"));
```